# why is the If statement is not working even if the condition is true? dart & flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dart, if-statement

why is the If (isNormal == true) statement is not working even if the condition is true

the code that I tried to do are as below

```
  _checkResult() {
    bool isNormal = false;
    isNormal = userAnswer.every((item) => normalList.contains(item));
    if (isNormal) {
      print("Normal");
    } else {
      print("Try Again");
    }
  }
```

I already tried to print both lists to check if both data are the same or not,

[image]

As you can see, both list are the same, but the result does not change. Please help

Comment: if you're not overriding the "equals" method, then "contains" is not going to work with custom classes. Plus, you're only checking the last value as the loop will check each item and when finished, only the last item will be checked for equality. Plus, you're checking if "isNormal" is negative to print "Normal" when you're getting a true value and the reason why it goes to "try again"

Comment: im so sorry I need to edit the code back. But even when i edit the !isNormal to isNormal, it still doesn't work

Comment: Provide more details about `normalList` and `userAnswer`

Comment: What does this do - userAnswer.every((item) => normalList.contains(item))?

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla I edited the code from !isNormal to isNormal but it didnt work, so do I need to try looping first then do if condition?

Comment: are you trying to check the list a contains all element on list b?

Comment: @rrttrr to check if list of userAnswer is the same as the list of normalList

Comment: @YeasinSheikh yes

Comment: What is this "-" in the list?

Comment: did you tried a conditional function?

Comment: @rrttrr it just a dash , means its nothing

Comment: @Stanly I haven't tried it yet because I'm not familiar with it

Comment: you only need to did something like this _isNormal ? print('Norma'l) :  print('Try Again')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow any of this

```dart
bool withEvery(List<int> mainItems, List<int> subItems) {
    final result = subItems.every((element) => mainItems.contains(element));
    return result;
  }
```

or

```
  bool containsItem(List<int> mainItems, List<int> subItems) {
    for (final i in subItems) {
      if (!mainItems.contains(i)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

to get desire result.

test case

```
  test("containsItem n check", () {
    final normalList = [1, 3, 2];
    final userAnswer = [1, 2, 3];
    final userAnswer1 = [2, 1, 3];
    final userAnswer2 = [2, 1, 0];
    final result = containsItem(normalList, userAnswer);
    expect(result, true);
    final result1 = containsItem(normalList, userAnswer1);
    expect(result1, true);
    final result2 = containsItem(normalList, userAnswer2);
    expect(result2, false);
  });

  test("withEvery ", () {
    final normalList = [1, 3, 2];
    final userAnswer = [1, 2, 3];
    final userAnswer1 = [2, 1, 3];
    final userAnswer2 = [2, 1, 0];
    final result = withEvery(normalList, userAnswer);
    expect(result, true);
    final result1 = withEvery(normalList, userAnswer1);
    expect(result1, true);
    final result2 = withEvery(normalList, userAnswer2);
    expect(result2, false);
  });
```

And your methods also working fine

[image]

Comment: I've tried it but I didn't work, I don't know what is wrong.

As I can see in your code you uses List<int>,

but in my code, normalList and UserAnswer, both uses List <Check>.

In Check() there is String id, answerText,

How do I uses If condition to check String id and answerText is the same for both lists?

Comment: you may need override the list equality if you like to compare the the intance

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question but
I assume you are trying to print 'Normal' when the list contents are same.
If so, then your if condition should be like this

`if(isNormal){ print('Normal'); }`

meaning you have to just put the bool variable as is, but you have used the Not (!) operator with it so its giving you the opposite result.

Comment: I pasted the wrong code just now, but I have edited the code. 

But even when i change the !isNormal to isNormal, it still doesn't work

Comment: are you using a List of custom class? because the code should work as is when the lists are of simple data types like int or string

Comment: yes Im using custom class where the class contain string id and answer